# What is the command line at GetCommandLine and at WinMain API?

Tags: c++, winforms, winapi, win32-process

For a Win32 application, what is the command line that I call GetCommandLine to get and send it as parameter for WinMain?

Comment: Please try to be more specific, It's hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: The command line is the text of the command that was used to start the process. For example, if in a console window you type `foo.exe bar` then a process based on the  `foo.exe` executable will be created with command line of `foo.exe bar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring issues of encoding and information loss, and glossing over what's a macro and what's a function, `GetCommandLine` is an API function that retrieves the original command line passed to the process, while `WinMain` is a function defined by your code that is called by Microsoft's C and C++ runtime support, and that is passed a copy of the part of the command line extending from the first argument and on, i.e. not including the program name/path at the start of the original command line.